# Android - How to upload image to Azure Storage Blob?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a selected image from the android device to Azure Blob Storage.

But my code fails at:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
```

Please Help! :)

Here is my code:

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.*;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.blob.client.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String storageConnectionString = 
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" + 
        "AccountName=myName;" + 
        "AccountKey=YOLO";

Uri currImageURI;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // To open up a gallery browser
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (requestCode == 1) {

                        // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the content:// URI of the image
                        currImageURI = data.getData();
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText(currImageURI.toString());

                         //Here starts the code for Azure Storage Blob
                        try{
                     // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
                        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

                        // Create the blob client
                        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

                        // Get a reference to a container
                        // The container name must be lower case
                        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("mycontainer");

                        // Create the container if it does not exist
                        container.createIfNotExist();

                        // Create a permissions object
                        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

                        // Include public access in the permissions object
                        containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);

                        // Set the permissions on the container
                        container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);

                        // Create or overwrite the "myimage.jpg" blob with contents from a local file
                        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("myimageYdolo.jpg");
                        File source = new File(currImageURI.toString());
                        blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){

                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The account key does not look correct to me. You can get it from the [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/). Navigate to storage account and look at the bottom for a "Manage Access Keys" button. You should see two keys, any of which you can use. See step by step instructions [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-storage-account/#regeneratestoragekeys).

Comment: I'm am not showing the original account key :) 
But the original account key works when I create a regular Java project. Only in Android it fails...

Comment: Makes sense that you did not include the original account key. What is the exception message?

Comment: 04-09 18:54:00.921: E/AndroidRuntime(7473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 18:54:00.921: E/AndroidRuntime(7473): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.CloudStorageAccount
04-09 18:54:00.921: E/AndroidRuntime(7473):  at com.example.uploadtest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:63)
04-09 18:54:00.921: E/AndroidRuntime(7473):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5385)
04-09 18:54:00.921: E/AndroidRuntime(7473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3843)

Comment: Do you by any chance have older versions of the library laying around in the build path or being referenced?

Comment: I don't think so, I downloaded the Azure Libraries from here: http://dl.msopentech.com/lib/PackageForWindowsAzureLibrariesForJava.html

Comment: I've made an WebService to solve this problem, please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966975/using-asp-net-webservice-android-to-upload-image-to-azure-blob-storage